# MySQL - Select and Update in a single command

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to select a `transactionID` from a MySQL table and immediately increment it.

```
SELECT transid FROM idtable;
UPDATE idtable SET transid=transid +1;
```

I would like to combine the queries but cannot get the correct syntax.

Comment: YOu understand that it is dangerous to do this correct? THat you can run into race conditions that will mees with the integrity of your data? WHy not use an autogenerated id?

Comment: @HLGEM: Are you confident the `transid` is a primary key? Not everyone knows proper SQL naming conventions. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a WHERE clause in your UPDATE will have the same effect.

```
UPDATE table
SET    column = column + 1
WHERE  column = value
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answers! The thinking behind combining the queries was that I could forsee the SELECT query being called by multiple users before it was updated. I realise now that it would be dangerous (I hadn't considered it!!).

Comment: One of the reasons for doing this is that some users are submitting updates more than once (accidentally). I simply wanted to create an ID number as a cross reference (has the transaction already been processed?). I had challenged my testers to try to cheat the results and some clever *** has found a way to submit the same update several times (I am assuming using an update URL), the transaction ID was an afterthought, it is not really required and would only be referred to once. - The project is a 'just for fun' learning experience for me, though might be useful in the furure.

Comment: So what's being inserted? You could always generate an MD5 or something of the actual results and use that at the key (though MD5 isn't truly unique, it would probably suffice for the sake of this project).

Comment: It is a simple voting 'game' and MD5 route would work perfectly. I already create a timestamp, which expires after 5 minutes. I can combine this with the exclusive data - which would give me an exclusive transaction ID. Mathematically it is possible to have the same ID but I can live with that! - Thanks for your help, lateral thinking solving the problem! My expertise is in getting data out of databases and doing clever stuff with it and updating results. This is my first real adventure into actual database design/programming. Clearly I have a lot to learn! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub-query style approach, but I have to wonder if there's any need for the initial SELECT. (Can't you just use a WHERE clause on the UPDATE, perhaps involving a multiple table join if so required.)

Take a look at the [MySQL UPDATE query syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for more information.